# How to sync two folders from AWS instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rsync

I have a `Rails` app which uploads files to a server and stores them so that they can be processed by a `Java` application.

The current configuration is in `AWS` which have two instances and is balanced by `ELB`.

Path to upload dir in AWS-instance1 : `/var/lib/rails_files`

Path to upload dir in AWS-instance2 : `/var/lib/rails_files`

Is there a way so that I can sync the directory `rails_files` from both instances?

At a specific time, the `Java` application looks for the file name from db and picks the file from `/var/lib/rails_files`.

Or is it possible to attach/add a shared drive to both instances so that it can be accessed from both instances?

I don't want to go with s3 file upload.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a service that matches exactly your requirements: [Amazon EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/)! But unfortunately, it is only available in Preview now. So at the moment, I guess you must configure NFS on your own

Comment: But even if you find a way to sync them, what do you do when you add a 3rd instance? Or if you replace an existing instance will the sync stil work?. The solution I see is the one you don't lke, upload the file to S3 and always take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than synchronizing between instances (and all the inherent security and configuration required), instead sync with Amazon S3.

For example, the [AWS Command-Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a command that can sync between local directories and an Amazon S3 bucket:

```
aws s3 sync dir s3://BUCKET/dir
```

This also works in the reverse direction (from S3 to local) and between S3 buckets. By default, `sync` will not delete files from the destination.